# WebRTC: коннект больше 2 пользователей

Tags: javascript, python, socket.io, streaming, webrtc

Пытаюсь написать приложение `WebRTC`, используя `socket.io`.

*Signalling server* написан на питоне

```
import socketio
import uvicorn
from starlette.applications import Starlette

ROOM = 'room'


sio = socketio.AsyncServer(async_mode='asgi', cors_allowed_origins='*')
star_app = Starlette(debug=True)
app = socketio.ASGIApp(sio, star_app)


@sio.event
async def connect(sid, environ):
    await sio.emit('ready', room=ROOM, skip_sid=sid)
    sio.enter_room(sid, ROOM)


@sio.event
async def data(sid, data):
    await sio.emit('data', data, room=ROOM, skip_sid=sid)


@sio.event
async def disconnect(sid):
    sio.leave_room(sid, ROOM)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    uvicorn.run(app, host='0.0.0.0', port=8003)
```

Код клиета

```
<script>
    const SIGNALING_SERVER_URL = 'http://127.0.0.1:8003?session_id=1';
    // WebRTC config: you don't have to change this for the example to work
    // If you are testing on localhost, you can just use PC_CONFIG = {}
    const PC_CONFIG = {};
 
    // Signaling methods
    let socket = io(SIGNALING_SERVER_URL, {autoConnect: false});
 
    socket.on('data', (data) => {
        console.log('Data received: ', data);
        handleSignalingData(data);
    });
 
    socket.on('ready', () => {
        console.log('Ready');
        // Connection with signaling server is ready, and so is local stream
        createPeerConnection();
        sendOffer();
    });
 
    let sendData = (data) => {
        socket.emit('data', data);
    };
 
    // WebRTC methods
    let pc;
    let localStream;
    let remoteStreamElement = document.querySelector('#remoteStream');
 
    let getLocalStream = () => {
        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio: true, video: true})
            .then((stream) => {
                console.log('Stream found');
                localStream = stream;
                // Connect after making sure that local stream is availble
                socket.connect();
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error('Stream not found: ', error);
            });
    }
 
    let createPeerConnection = () => {
        try {
            pc = new RTCPeerConnection(PC_CONFIG);
            pc.onicecandidate = onIceCandidate;
            pc.onaddstream = onAddStream;
            pc.addStream(localStream);
            console.log('PeerConnection created');
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('PeerConnection failed: ', error);
        }
    };
 
    let sendOffer = () => {
        console.log('Send offer');
        pc.createOffer().then(
            setAndSendLocalDescription,
            (error) => {
                console.error('Send offer failed: ', error);
            }
        );
    };
 
    let sendAnswer = () => {
        console.log('Send answer');
        pc.createAnswer().then(
            setAndSendLocalDescription,
            (error) => {
                console.error('Send answer failed: ', error);
            }
        );
    };
 
    let setAndSendLocalDescription = (sessionDescription) => {
        pc.setLocalDescription(sessionDescription);
        console.log('Local description set');
        sendData(sessionDescription);
    };
 
    let onIceCandidate = (event) => {
        if (event.candidate) {
            console.log('ICE candidate');
            sendData({
                type: 'candidate',
                candidate: event.candidate
            });
        }
    };
 
    let onAddStream = (event) => {
        console.log('Add stream');
        remoteStreamElement.srcObject = event.stream;
    };
 
    let handleSignalingData = (data) => {
        // let msg = JSON.parse(data);
        switch (data.type) {
            case 'offer':
                createPeerConnection();
                pc.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(data));
                sendAnswer();
                break;
            case 'answer':
                pc.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(data));
                break;
            case 'candidate':
                pc.addIceCandidate(new RTCIceCandidate(data.candidate));
                break;
        }
    };
 
    // Start connection
    getLocalStream();
</script>
```

Также использую *socket.io* библиотеку

https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/blob/master/client-dist/socket.io.js

Когда два человека в коннекте - все отлично работает. *Но как только к ним пытается подключиться третий пользователь, стриминг останавливается с ошибкой*

> Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to execute 'setRemoteDescription' on 'RTCPeerConnection': Failed to set remote answer sdp: Called in wrong state: stable

Ошибка эта прослеживается во всех браузерах.

**Репозиторий с докером:**

https://github.com/pfertyk/webrtc-working-example

**Инструкция:**

https://pfertyk.me/2020/03/webrtc-a-working-example/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
'use strict';

const startButton = document.getElementById('startButton');
const callButton1 = document.getElementById('callButton1');
const callButton2 = document.getElementById('callButton2');
const hangupButton = document.getElementById('hangupButton');

callButton1.disabled = true;
callButton2.disabled = true;
hangupButton.disabled = true;
startButton.onclick = start;
callButton1.onclick = callTwo;
callButton2.onclick = callAttach;
hangupButton.onclick = hangup;

const offerOptions = {
  offerToReceiveAudio: 1,
  offerToReceiveVideo: 1
};
const servers = null;

console.log = () => {}

function gotStream(stream) {
  console.log('Получаем локальный стрим с камеры');
  document.querySelector('video#video1').srcObject = stream;
  window.localStream = stream;
  callButton1.disabled = false;
}
function start() {
  console.log('Запрос на получение локального стрима с камеры');
  startButton.disabled = true;
  navigator.mediaDevices
      .getUserMedia({
        audio: true,
        video: true
      })
      .then(gotStream)
      .catch(e => console.log('getUserMedia() error: ', e));
}
class PeerConnection {
  constructor(videoElement){
    this.videoElement = videoElement;
    this.pcLocal = new RTCPeerConnection(servers);
    this.pcRemote = new RTCPeerConnection(servers);
    this.pcRemote.ontrack = this.gotRemoteStream;
    this.pcLocal.onicecandidate = this.iceCallbackLocal;
    this.pcRemote.onicecandidate = this.iceCallbackRemote;
    // создаем оффер для подключения
    window.localStream.getTracks().forEach(track => this.pcLocal.addTrack(track, window.localStream));
    this.pcLocal
      .createOffer(offerOptions)
        .then(this.gotDescriptionLocal, onCreateSessionDescriptionError);
  }  
  gotDescriptionLocal = (desc) => {
    this.pcLocal.setLocalDescription(desc);
    console.log(`Установили локальное описание\n${desc.sdp}`);
    this.pcRemote.setRemoteDescription(desc);
    // отсылаем одобрение на получение видео
    this.pcRemote.createAnswer().then(this.gotDescriptionRemote, onCreateSessionDescriptionError);
  }
  gotDescriptionRemote = (desc) => {
    this.pcRemote.setLocalDescription(desc);
    console.log(`Получили ответ с удаленного соединения\n${desc.sdp}`);
    this.pcLocal.setRemoteDescription(desc);
  }
  gotRemoteStream = (e) => {
    if (this.videoElement.srcObject !== e.streams[0]) {
      this.videoElement.srcObject = e.streams[0];
      console.log('pc: получаем и отображаем удаленный стрим');
    }
  }
  iceCallbackLocal = (event) => {
    if (event.candidate){
      handleCandidate(event.candidate, this.pcRemote, 'pc: ', 'локальный кандидат на удаленном соединении');
    }
  }
  iceCallbackRemote = (event) => {
    if (event.candidate){
      handleCandidate(event.candidate, this.pcLocal, 'pc: ', 'удаленный кандидат на локальном соединении');
    }
  }
  close(){
    // закрываем соединения
    this.pcLocal.close();
    this.pcRemote.close();
    this.pcLocal = this.pcRemote = null;
  }
}
// два удаленных соединения (соединение локальное + удалленое)
let pc1 = null;
let pc2 = null;

function callTwo() {
  callButton1.disabled = true;
  callButton2.disabled = false;
  hangupButton.disabled = false;
  console.log('Начало звонка');
  const audioTracks = window.localStream.getAudioTracks();
  const videoTracks = window.localStream.getVideoTracks();
  if (audioTracks.length > 0) {
    console.log(`Используется аудио устройство: ${audioTracks[0].label}`);
  }
  if (videoTracks.length > 0) {
    console.log(`Используется видео устройство: ${videoTracks[0].label}`);
  }
  // инициализация участников
  pc1 = new PeerConnection(document.querySelector('video#video2'))
  //pc2 = new PeerConnection(document.querySelector('video#video3'))
}
function callAttach() {
  callButton2.disabled = true;
  pc2 = new PeerConnection(document.querySelector('video#video3'))
}
// положить трубку
function hangup() {
  console.log('Ending calls');
  pc1.close();
  pc2.close();
  hangupButton.disabled = true;
  callButton1.disabled = false;
}

// добавление кандидатов к соединению
function handleCandidate(candidate, dest, prefix, type) {
  dest.addIceCandidate(candidate)
      .then(onAddIceCandidateSuccess, onAddIceCandidateError);
  console.log(`${prefix}New ${type} ICE candidate: ${candidate ? candidate.candidate : '(null)'}`);
}
// обработчик успешного добавления участника
function onAddIceCandidateSuccess() {
  console.log('AddIceCandidate success.');
}
// обработчик ошибки добавления участника
function onAddIceCandidateError(error) {
  console.log(`Failed to add ICE candidate: ${error.toString()}`);
}
// обработчик ошибки создания описания 
function onCreateSessionDescriptionError(error) {
  console.log(`Failed to create session description: ${error.toString()}`);
}
```

```css
video {
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
  <video id="video1" playsinline autoplay muted></video>
  <video id="video2" playsinline autoplay></video>
  <video id="video3" playsinline autoplay></video>
  <div>
    <button id="startButton">Получить стрим</button>
    <button id="callButton1">Соединение 2х</button>
    <button id="callButton2">Подключение 1го</button>
    <button id="hangupButton">Завершить</button>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Небольшой пример кода демонстрирующий соединение 2 узлов при последующем подсоединении третьего узла, к сожалению тут это не работает, поэтому [ссылка на песочницу](https://codepen.io/Danwillzoom/pen/qBqpjqr) в данном примере трансляция идет только с первого узла.

Коментарии присутствуют в коде, но приложу небольшое объяснение. Мы здесь не используем ни STUN ни TURN серверы для передачи данных, все что можно и нужно работает однако пересылка стрима осуществляется через глобальную переменну что при наличие сокет соединения легко переделать. Каждое соединение хранит 2 узла локальный и удаленный и между ними собственно и создается связь поэтому не происходит никаких конфликтов (два узла - одна связь) Создаем офер, тут же отправляем ответ, подключаем кандидатов в оба конца и связь налажена.

[Рекомендую учебник на русском](https://coderlessons.com/tutorials/veb-razrabotka/uznaite-webrtc/webrtc-tutorial) так как в сети не так уж и много информации на этот счет и большинство на английском.

И разумеется не будет лишним посмотреть [демонстрации WebRTC APIs](https://webrtc.github.io/samples/) там же есть ссылка на их [исходники на GitHub](https://github.com/webrtc/samples)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Проблема моя в том, что я вместо создания нового соединения `RTCPeerConnection` использую текущее (при коннекте третьего юзера). Сейчас буду смотреть, как это фиксить.

Comment: Если я дам ссылку на гит с докером, сможете проверить?

Comment: ссылка не нужна у меня получилось поставить попробую разобраться с вопросом

Comment: @m0nte-cr1st0 я обновил ответ, к сожалению был занят, этот пример кода еще можно улучшать но я оставил его максимально простым чтобы многие могли бы им воспользоваться.