# WebRTC не передает видео поток с андроида на другие девайсы

Tags: javascript, webrtc

Ошибка в консоле андроида

```
Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to execute 'setRemoteDescription' on 'RTCPeerConnection': Failed to set remote answer sdp: Failed to set remote video description send parameters for m-section with mid='1'.
```

с чем это может быть связанно? я плохо разбираюсь в WebRTC но наш разраб куда то пропал а проблему нужно решить, по этому буду благодарен за любую помощь

```
OFFER FOR MOBILE  message SDP v=0
o=- 6660171685958775296 2 IN IP4 127.0.0.1
s=-
t=0 0
a=group:BUNDLE audio video
a=extmap-allow-mixed
a=msid-semantic: WMS stream_screen_test@gmail.com
m=audio 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 111 103 104 9 102 0 8 106 105 13 110 112 113 126
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=ice-ufrag:gA9/
a=ice-pwd:JyteSnWTnx8Siam/eFRXg/Q/
a=ice-options:trickle
a=fingerprint:sha-256 57:41:5E:1E:3B:08:F7:E3:88:00:15:DE:86:D8:0A:4F:12:62:8F:33:65:5D:32:6D:C0:8F:47:E8:45:D1:88:88
a=setup:actpass
a=mid:audio
a=extmap:1 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:ssrc-audio-level
a=extmap:2 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time
a=extmap:3 http://www.ietf.org/id/draft-holmer-rmcat-transport-wide-cc-extensions-01
a=sendonly
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtpmap:111 opus/48000/2
a=rtcp-fb:111 transport-cc
a=fmtp:111 minptime=10;useinbandfec=1
a=rtpmap:103 ISAC/16000
a=rtpmap:104 ISAC/32000
a=rtpmap:9 G722/8000
a=rtpmap:102 ILBC/8000
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a=rtpmap:106 CN/32000
a=rtpmap:105 CN/16000
a=rtpmap:13 CN/8000
a=rtpmap:110 telephone-event/48000
a=rtpmap:112 telephone-event/32000
a=rtpmap:113 telephone-event/16000
a=rtpmap:126 telephone-event/8000
a=ssrc:468693706 cname:F5S6TRP+lchzOc9A
a=ssrc:468693706 msid:stream_screen_test@gmail.com prodvd_mixed_audio_track
a=ssrc:468693706 mslabel:stream_screen_test@gmail.com
a=ssrc:468693706 label:prodvd_mixed_audio_track
m=video 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 96 97 98 99 100 101 127
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=ice-ufrag:gA9/
a=ice-pwd:JyteSnWTnx8Siam/eFRXg/Q/
a=ice-options:trickle
a=fingerprint:sha-256 57:41:5E:1E:3B:08:F7:E3:88:00:15:DE:86:D8:0A:4F:12:62:8F:33:65:5D:32:6D:C0:8F:47:E8:45:D1:88:88
a=setup:actpass
a=mid:video
a=extmap:14 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:toffset
a=extmap:2 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time
a=extmap:13 urn:3gpp:video-orientation
a=extmap:3 http://www.ietf.org/id/draft-holmer-rmcat-transport-wide-cc-extensions-01
a=extmap:5 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/playout-delay
a=extmap:6 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/video-content-type
a=extmap:7 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/video-timing
a=extmap:8 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/color-space
a=sendonly
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtcp-rsize
a=rtpmap:96 H264/90000
a=rtcp-fb:96 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:96 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:96 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:96 nack
a=rtcp-fb:96 nack pli
a=fmtp:96 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=42e01f
a=rtpmap:97 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:97 apt=96
a=rtpmap:98 H264/90000
a=rtcp-fb:98 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:98 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:98 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:98 nack
a=rtcp-fb:98 nack pli
a=fmtp:98 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=0;profile-level-id=42e01f
a=rtpmap:99 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:99 apt=98
a=rtpmap:100 red/90000
a=rtpmap:101 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:101 apt=100
a=rtpmap:127 ulpfec/90000
a=ssrc-group:FID 469637419 459830099
a=ssrc:469637419 cname:F5S6TRP+lchzOc9A
a=ssrc:469637419 msid:stream_screen_test@gmail.com prodvd_screen_video_track
a=ssrc:469637419 mslabel:stream_screen_test@gmail.com
a=ssrc:469637419 label:prodvd_screen_video_track
a=ssrc:459830099 cname:F5S6TRP+lchzOc9A
a=ssrc:459830099 msid:stream_screen_test@gmail.com prodvd_screen_video_track
a=ssrc:459830099 mslabel:stream_screen_test@gmail.com
a=ssrc:459830099 label:prodvd_screen_video_track




ANSWER FROM MOBILE message SDP v=0
o=- 1873510526954684693 2 IN IP4 127.0.0.1
s=-
t=0 0
a=group:BUNDLE 0 1
a=extmap-allow-mixed
a=msid-semantic: WMS stream_camera_test@gmail.com
m=audio 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 111 103 9 0 8 105 13 110 113 126
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=ice-ufrag:/PIk
a=ice-pwd:7TxW5VszZJeBnWtV+DJfCt+t
a=ice-options:trickle
a=fingerprint:sha-256 E3:F5:B5:1F:83:8F:4B:33:8D:50:3C:70:A0:A8:C3:5E:59:59:78:04:E4:6D:07:03:09:D0:79:39:04:C3:24:AE
a=setup:active
a=mid:0
a=extmap:1 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:ssrc-audio-level
a=extmap:2 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time
a=extmap:3 http://www.ietf.org/id/draft-holmer-rmcat-transport-wide-cc-extensions-01
a=recvonly
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtpmap:111 opus/48000/2
a=rtcp-fb:111 transport-cc
a=fmtp:111 minptime=10;useinbandfec=1
a=rtpmap:103 ISAC/16000
a=rtpmap:9 G722/8000
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a=rtpmap:105 CN/16000
a=rtpmap:13 CN/8000
a=rtpmap:110 telephone-event/48000
a=rtpmap:113 telephone-event/16000
a=rtpmap:126 telephone-event/8000
m=video 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 108 109 127
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=ice-ufrag:/PIk
a=ice-pwd:7TxW5VszZJeBnWtV+DJfCt+t
a=ice-options:trickle
a=fingerprint:sha-256 E3:F5:B5:1F:83:8F:4B:33:8D:50:3C:70:A0:A8:C3:5E:59:59:78:04:E4:6D:07:03:09:D0:79:39:04:C3:24:AE
a=setup:active
a=mid:1
a=extmap:14 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:toffset
a=extmap:2 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time
a=extmap:13 urn:3gpp:video-orientation
a=extmap:3 http://www.ietf.org/id/draft-holmer-rmcat-transport-wide-cc-extensions-01
a=extmap:5 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/playout-delay
a=extmap:6 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/video-content-type
a=extmap:7 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/video-timing
a=extmap:8 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/color-space
a=sendrecv
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtcp-rsize
a=rtpmap:108 red/90000
a=rtpmap:109 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:109 apt=108
a=rtpmap:127 ulpfec/90000
a=ssrc-group:FID 3016246175 1332567548
a=ssrc:3016246175 cname:NGKF2cIX1VMriG1p
a=ssrc:3016246175 msid:stream_camera_test@gmail.com prodvd_camera_video_track
a=ssrc:3016246175 mslabel:stream_camera_test@gmail.com
a=ssrc:3016246175 label:prodvd_camera_video_track
a=ssrc:1332567548 cname:NGKF2cIX1VMriG1p
a=ssrc:1332567548 msid:stream_camera_test@gmail.com prodvd_camera_video_track
a=ssrc:1332567548 mslabel:stream_camera_test@gmail.com
a=ssrc:1332567548 label:prodvd_camera_video_track
```

Comment: только с андроидом так?

Comment: да на остальных платформах всё ок и у IOS тоже всё работает

Comment: на англоязычном [ресурсе](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69937781/why-am-i-getting-failed-to-set-remote-video-description-send-parameters-for-m-s) пишут что действительно есть такая проблема с андроидами, связана она с кодеками `H264 codecs`, там правда соединение создается на Java, поэтому не уверен что тот ответ поможет

Comment: В любом случае думаю в этом вопросе не помешал бы минимально воспроизводимый пример, так больше шансов получить помощь

Comment: Я бы показал бы пример но тут на одном только классе c  ивентами webrtc больше 700+ строк, по этому хотя бы хочу понять в какую сторону мне копать чтоб решить проблему,  да на англоязычном ресурсе говорят про кодек и во многих форумах так же

Comment: Вот подвернулась [статья на инглише](https://medium.com/bumble-tech/webrtc-on-android-how-to-enable-hardware-encoding-on-multiple-devices-5bd819c0ce5) возможно поможет

Comment: У меня есть подозрение что все эти трюки в браузере на простом js не прокрутить, но есть [cтрим с песочницей](https://webrtccourse.com/course/webrtc-codelab/module/fiddle-of-the-month/lesson/finding-codec-capabilities/) где можно глянуть совместимость, я бы отталкивался от этого

Comment: @DaniilLoban я изучаю код и в процессе вижу что в sdp offer равен a=group:BUNDLE audio video в asnwer sdp равен a=group:BUNDLE 0 1 может ли быть так что проблема из-за этого? я дополнил вопрос и написал полный sdp от answer и offer

Comment: C WebRTC не все так просто, его нужно покрутить с разных сторон, причина может быть в чем угодно, оставлю ссылку на мой [другой ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1240457/webrtc-коннект-больше-2-пользователей/1244115#1244115) по этой технологии (документации полагаю и сейчас не много), надеюсь он будет как-то полезен особенно обратите внимание на ссылки - Вам поможет если найдете там то, что у Вас заработает, если не поможет, то нужно будет кидать этот вопрос в конкурсы разумеется дополняя теми деталями о которых попросят, у меня сейчас даже нет подходящего железа чтобы тестировать.